# Not able to execute copy command in bat from PHP

Tags: php, windows, batch-file

I am trying a really simple thing in PHP. I want to execute an external bat file from PHP script, which is invoked from web server (Apache with WAMP). Following is the content of bat file named savereport.bat

```
echo %PATH% > C:\project\mypath.txt
cp D:\books\Ant\1.pdf D:\books\Ant\2.pdf
```

The bat file when executed manually works fine, it creates mypath.txt in C:\project directory and 1.pdf is copied to 2.pdf correctly.

However, when I run the same bat file from PHP with system(), only the first statement completes, which means it does create C:\project\mypath.txt, but strangely it does not copy 1.pdf to 2.pdf.

This is the PHP code I am using

```
<?php
system('C:\wamp\www\savereport.bat');
?>
```

I have also tried exec(), passthru, same result in all the case. Please help.

Comment: I think 'cp' is not a native windows command. If it's something you added to your windows installation, PHP's system() call probably could not find it in the PATH. Have you tried the 'copy' command?

Answer (score 1):

`cp` is not a windows command, it's probably a Powershell alias, replace the `cp` with `copy`.

Comment: Yes, I had git bash and cygwin installed, that's why it recognized cp when run manually, since the apache server was running with different user. hence PATH information specific to cp wasn't avaiable. I could find the following info in apache_error.log

'cp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: OK, so did you change the command from `cp` to `copy` and re-checked?

Comment: yes , It worked :) I was trying CP just as an example, after realizing the unavailability of PATH info, i provided the fully absolute path of exe i wanted to execute, which is wkhtmltopdf, so the new code is now
exec("C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf.exe") . It works now!